# How to make a Tkinter window jump to the front? after mainloop()

Tags: python, tkinter

How do I get a Tkinter application to jump to the front when The application is minimized to the dock?
I use :
  `os.system('''/usr/bin/osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to set frontmost of process "autoinstall" to true' ''')`
I find it can reopen Safair, but not  Tkinter application, because this code call after mainloop()
What's the best way to deal with my situation?

Comment: I didn't get, what `.mainloop()` have to do with it? [Edit] your Question and the relevant code.

Comment: @stovfl Thank you for your reply, 
I found a solution，that is : tell application "your appName"
             reopen -- unminimizes the first minimized window or makes a new default window
                activate -- makes the app frontmost
            end tell